# Java - How to get and read a certificate for https://google.com

Tags: java, certificate

I am trying to get and read a certificate for https://google.com, but I'm having the biggest issues which classes I should use. Where is a good starting place to read certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Here is explain step by step and please also search in google.

> > http://www.searchenginejournal.com/get-google-adwords-certification-free/71929/

Good Luck.